# Inline text rotation

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I want to have italic text, however I want to be able to play with the rotation. I know for plain italic text, I can do `<i></i>` or `font-style: italic`, but what if I want to rotate the text by a custom amount of degrees. Is there a way to do that?

Simple `transform: rotate(5deg)` won't work because that will not rotate the text inline, like italic does. Is there a way to do this, and if so, how do you recommend I go about it?

Comment: Check this link, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Fonts/Variable_Fonts_Guide

Comment: ... specially the "slant" section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, but I think CSS [`skew()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/skew) transform property would be the best approach to get what you want.

The `skew()` will accept two properties *(`skew(ax, ay)`)* for distorting the element in x and y axes, but in your current particular case passing the first parameter would be enough.

So your final code would be something like this:

```css
.skew {
  transform: skew(15deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="skew">hi there</div>
```